# Buttons in a circle path animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation

I have followed this tutorial -> [Align buttons in a Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764939/how-to-align-uibuttons-within-a-circle)

Now i want to animate these buttons in a smooth way, Anyone can suggest me possible type of animations i can do here.?

If you guys already worked with any libraries which does this kind of animation, please suggest me.

here my view, i want to these english letter, at the time of displaying this subview.[image]

Comment: Are you want to like wise develop? http://youtu.be/9uszKz4Ct8U

Comment: @NimitParekh That would be cool.

Comment: @NimitParekh Where can i find the code.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is the library code for the what you want to develop.

1. [ALRadial](https://github.com/alattis/ALRadial)
2. [QuadCurveMenu](https://github.com/burtlo/QuadCurveMenu)
3. [KYCircleMenu](https://github.com/Kjuly/KYCircleMenu)
4. [ASRadial](https://github.com/alpersenyurt/ASRadial)
5. [LIVBubbleMenu-iOS](https://github.com/limitlessvirtual/LIVBubbleMenu-iOS)

May this help lot.